# How to concatenate to each string in an array in lua?

Tags: arrays, string, lua, concatenation

I need to concatenate a string to each of an array of strings. Is there a better way to do this? (Some vectorized or built-in method?)

```
for i=1,10 do
    stringList[i] = stringList[i] .. "NewHotness"
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin method for doing that. Your solution is just fine.